# How to rename a batch of files using a list/database

Tags: applescript, osx-elcapitan, automator, finder

I'm trying to batch rename a load of Word documents and I'd like to do it using a database of names. I already have an excel spreadsheet with the names I want to use in Column 1, but I have around 300 of them and it's going to take me ages to copy and paste them all in. I was looking into Automator. I did find this: https://discussions.apple.com/message/31457698#31457698 and I'm attempting to modify it for my needs but would appreciate a clearer solution.

I'm on a Macbook Pro running OS X El Capitan.

Anyone know of a way?

Thanks!

Comment: add some code here

Comment: It would be easiest to copy your list out of excel and paste it into a simple text document. Then you read the text document with your script, loop through the lines and do your work on each iteration of the loop. You can use excel, but it adds another layer of complexity that it doesn't appear you really need.